# Remove everything but numbers and minus sign PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've currently got

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]/s', '', $myvariable);
```

For example the input is GB -3.  My current line is giving me the value 3.  I want to be able to keep the minus so that the value shows -3 instead of the current output of 3.

Comment: Then add the minus to the character class...

Comment: Add the `-` in your bracket expression at the end?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this :

```
preg_replace('/[^\d-]+/', '', $myvariable);
```

breakdown of regex:

- `//` on both sides are regex delimiter - everything that is inside is regex
- `[]` means that this is character class. [Rules change in character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `^` inside character class stands for "not".
- `\d` is short for [0-9], only difference is that it can be used both inside and outside of character class
- `-` will match minus sign
- `+` in the end is the quantifier, it means that this should match one or more characters

Comment: Thank you,  Answer will be accepted in 10 minutes when allowed.

Comment: @Oussama -- For preg_replace , how do we strip out anything which is NOT in the format like 100.15 or 100 or -235.16 where the negative in front is optional and the decimal point plus the two decimals in the back is optional too ? I have tried putting [+-]? in front but to no avail . Pattern /  -?[^0-9]*[.]?[^0-9]?[^0-9]?    / is not fully working also

Comment: @MarcoZen could you share the answer to your problem if you had found it? I need to replace `-` (minus) sign if it is not at the start of the number

Comment: @SarojShrestha - wait ...  let me dig this up ....Cant remember ...

Comment: "^[+-]?[0-9]{0,13}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"  -> I used this for a 13 digit  positive or negative number